# Allow PHP to read GET with RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

`RewriteRule ^cards/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /cards/?name=$1&page=$2 [L]`

Hi. I have this inside my .htaccess. If I add ?extra=1 to the end of the url and then var_dump, it doesn't read the $_GET['extra'];
Is there a flag that works?

I saw [here](https://getdocs.org/Apache-http-server/docs/latest/rewrite/flags) some extra flags but none seems of any use in this particular situation.

Comment: You do not need to perform any magic to achieve what you ask. That _should_ work out of the box. If it does not work for you then there has to be another reason. Either the rule does not get applied or an older version of the rule without the parameter gets applied or you make a mistake when reading the value or you are looking at a cached result.

Comment: @arkascha 1) the rule does get applied or I wouldn't be able to see the page 2) I don't see any other "^cards" rules inside .htaccess 3) I var_dump'd $_GET, I don't know what else to do 4) cache can't be a problem because the page updates everything else plus I'm doing Ctrl+F5 every time. Tried on another browser but nothing. 
I have several other rules. Here's a summary:
ErrorDocument 404
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
ExpiresActive On
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache

Comment: Not much more I can offer. Maybe you want to enable rewrite logging. That allows to understand in detail what is going on inside your rewriting engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I saw here some extra flags but none seems of any use in this particular situation.

If you are expecting the query string on the original request to be *merged* with the query string in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (2nd argument of the `RewriteRule` directive) then you need to add the [`QSA` flag](https://getdocs.org/Apache-http-server/docs/latest/rewrite/flags#QSA.7Cqsappend) (Query String Append) to your rule. The default behaviour is that any query string in the substitution will override the request.

However, you should be rewriting to the actual file that handles the request, not the *directory* (and presumably expecting mod_dir to issue an internal subrequest for the directory index).

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^cards/([^/]+)/([^/]*)$ /cards/index.php?name=$1&page=$2 [QSA,L]
```

*Aside:* I also changed the first quantifier from `*` to `+` since the path segment cannot be *empty* for the rule to be successful.